# Yum dependencies

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

please advice

when i install the RPM - subscription-manager-1.11.3-14.el5_11.i386.rpm

its fail about missing RPM ( dependencies )

but the RPM are already installed - how it can be?

```
  20:37:23 root@obama:/tmp # rpm -i  subscription-manager-1.11.3-14.el5_11.i386.rpm
  error: Failed dependencies:
  pygobject2 is needed by subscription-manager-1.11.3-14.el5_11.i386
  python-rhsm >= 1.11.3-5 is needed by subscription-manager-1.11.3-  14.el5_11.i386

  20:37:34 root@obama:/tmp # rpm -qa|grep pygobject
  pygobject2-doc-2.12.1-5.el5

  20:37:46 root@obama:/tmp # rpm -qa|grep python-rhsm
  python-rhsm-1.8.17-1.el5

  20:37:57 root@obama:/tmp #
```

or

```
yum localinstall pygobject2-doc-2.12.1-5.el5.i386.rpm
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin

Setting up Local Package Process
Examining pygobject2-doc-2.12.1-5.el5.i386.rpm: pygobject2-doc-2.12.1-5.el5.i386
pygobject2-doc-2.12.1-5.el5.i386.rpm: does not update installed package.
```

Nothing to do

This is a local machine unable to connect to external network

Comment: Rpm asks about pygobject2 and you are installing pygobject2-doc. You don't have required package. As for python package there is a version requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm` command does not resolve dependencies. Try `yum install subscription-manager` instead. Yum will resolve dependencies.

Comment: see my update with yum installed

Comment: you did not do what I told you to do.

Comment: this is local machine without enable to connect ext network

Comment: You should have said that before. I have no idea what repositories you have access to. You need to explain your set up better.

Comment: ok I am very sorry about this hope its clear now

Comment: no, it is not..